# Disk mounted shows wrong size in df, and appears empty

Tags: partitioning, mount

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

This is my `fstab`

```
UUID=dcd55b7f-3157-4e75-9372-bcab5b0ac7cf   /    ext4   defaults,discard    0 0
/dev/sdc1   /mnt/DATA   auto    defaults    0   0
```

The problem is on `/dev/sdc1` (ext4). At boot it is mounted correctly but with `df -h` it shows the wrong size and the disk appears to be empty.

If I do `umount /dev/sdc1` and then `mount -a` it works, the disk has the right size and the data appears.

If I reboot the problem appears again.

Thanks.

Comment: This is interesting. I have a feeling that this is a bug though.

Comment: what is the filesystem of `/dev/sdc1`? And you have `autofs` package installed?

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What exactly does `df` and `mount` say after a reboot?

Comment: the filesystem is `ext4`. `df` after reboot shows the disk as mounted but with the wrong size, and if I `ls` on it, it is empty. The same disk, on Ubuntu 13, is mounted perfectly, with the same fstab

Answer (score -1):

This happends because you want to mount the second filesystem on a catalog in the first filesystem. But as you have the last number on both filesystems set to 0, whichever is mounted first is a bit random.

Change the second one to 1 like this:

```
/dev/sdc1   /mnt/DATA   auto    defaults    0   1
```

Then it will be mounted after the first one is up and running.

More information:

> man fstab

and check under "The sixth field (fs_passno)"

Comment: it does not work.

Comment: No, the 6th field is for when it should be fscked, not mounted, and it is ignored these days anyhow.

Comment: Maybe this will help: The root filesystem should be specified with a fs_passno of 1, and other filesystems should have a fs_passno of 2.

Comment: I would also change auto to ext4, to be sure of a fast mount.